# how to compare object.key in array in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops, compare

In Table user can select any number of rows to upload on  "**upload API**" but in those selected Rows any one of the row contains status as "**NOT OK**"  I need to show popup that there is "not ok" status please "deselect" that row, if the rows contains status OK then I have to call "**upload API**".

```
onUpload(){
  let selectedRows=this.agGrid.api.getSelectedRows();
  selectedRows.forEach((row:any,i:any)=>{
 if( row.status==='OK'){
  /** upload API CALL **/
    }else{
     
     this.isTooltipUpload=true;
  setTimeout(()=>{
  this.isTooltipUpload=false;
},2000)
    }
  })
}

selectedRows :[
{athlete: 'Michael Phelps', age: 23, status:'OK', year: 2008, date: '24/08/2008', …}

{athlete: 'Michael Phelps', age: 19, status:'OK', year: 2004, date: '29/08/2004', …}

{athlete: 'Michael Phelps', age: 27, status:'Not ok', year: 2012, date: '12/08/2012', …}
]
```

here I am looping the **selectedRows** using **forEach** method and comparing the **row.status==='OK'**, if it is true I need to Call API else need to show popup(this.isTooltipUpload=true).

what I am getting:

in selectedRows even status is 'NOT OK' "if"(if condition false) condition is calling the API  and else calling the popup

can any one please help me where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code considers each row separately, checking if each individual one is valid. You directly make an API call when the current row is valid, without having ensured that every single row is valid beforehand.

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any row is not valid before attempting API calls.

```js
if (selectedRows.some(r => r.status !== 'OK')) {
    // show error popup
} else {
    // loop over selectedRows and make each API call
}
```